# Kendo-Ui directives not working when lazy loading with oc.lazyLoad

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, lazy-loading

I want to load the 'kendo.directives' angularJS module with lazy loading using [ocLazyLoad](https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad). Here is my simple example code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="ocLazyLoad.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="example" ng-app="LazyLoadTest" ng-controller="TestController">

    </div>
    <script>
        angular.module("LazyLoadTest", [ "oc.lazyLoad"])
            .controller("TestController", function($scope, $ocLazyLoad, $compile, $timeout){
                $ocLazyLoad.load({
                        name: "kendo.directives",
                        files: ["http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/js/kendo.all.min.js"],
                        serie: true
                    }).then(function () {
                        var el, elToAppend, compiled;
                        var targetElement = angular.element('#example');
                        el = angular.element('<input kendo-date-picker />');
                        compiled = $compile(el);
                        targetElement.append(el);
                        compiled($scope);
                    }, function (e) {
                        console.log(e);
                    })
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The input field should become a date-picker as described [here](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/datepicker/angular). But nothing happens.

I have created a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/fK2rEKDDHxHZHmZ4sZCr?p=preview).

Comment: If you're using $stateProvider, use $ocLazyLoad in resolve. Otherwise, add $timeout(function(){ $scope.$apply(); },0);  (include '$timeout' with $scope above) and see if kendo directive works.

Comment: I tried just now but it seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the report, this is now fixed in the library with the following commit: https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad/commit/6bbaed971cf2d23bb35a6ba5f29c6e6162edc5b5 !

It turns out that they are registering multiple directive with the same name but with different functions.

Don't do that in your code guys because you will make angular execute the directive wrappers multiple times and that's far from optimal.

But in the case of kendo they do that because they have automated the directive registering process and they only execute the differences when they register the directive a second time (the first registration is the generic stuff). Also they deal with aliases.

They probably should do that without registering the directive twice but go figure...

Anyway, it should work now !

Answer (score -1):

I think you should add the kendo.directives as a dependency to the `testApp` module.

Comment: The testApp module does not require the kendo.directives module. kendo.directives should be bootstraped directly into the LazyLoadTest module by ocLazyLoad so that the directives are available.

Comment: Correct, I overlooked that, you do not need them there. One other thing you may try is to compile the content after it has been appended into the document.

Comment: I think I have found what you meant with compiling after appending. I have edited my question and also added a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/fK2rEKDDHxHZHmZ4sZCr?p=preview). I am I now doing what you suggested?

Comment: I did open an issue on [ocLazyLoad](https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad/issues/120) but I am not sure whether this rather might be a problem of kendo-ui.